# Need week number of year in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql, reporting-services

hoping someone can help -- Googling provided none.  I need to get the week number (of the year) from a date.  I've added field "week_num" to my dataset and when I went to create the expression, I see there is no "WEEK" function under Date/Time?

In VB and other languages there is a simple week function but I don't see it in SSRS 2008.  For example, if the date is '2014-03-16', I want the week number, which is 12.

can anyone help?

Comment: [**DATEPART(week, '2014-03-16')**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: thanks!  I Googled that function and found this:  DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Parameters!MyDate.Value)    just using "week" didn't work, that's not a valid function in SSRS 2008.  Thanks!

Comment: The code DATEPART(week, '2014-03-16') is SQL query language whereas the code you posted Kim is SSRS's expression language. A notable difference.

Comment: Note that SSRS uses only one of the week numbering systems - and it's not the ISO one!

Answer (score 14):

regarding this question, i had the same issue, (kinda sucks that SSRS does not share same function references and params that MSSQL being part of it ) but here's the instruction set for datepart, in this case directly for SSRS>

for this date as example>

```
=DatePart(DateInterval.Month, today())
```

this will output current date's month number.

here's a list for some valid dateinterval parameters, in SSRS datepart function

- DateInterval.Second
- DateInterval.Minute
- DateInterval.Hour
- DateInterval.Weekday
- DateInterval.Day
- DateInterval.DayOfYear
- DateInterval.WeekOfYear
- DateInterval.Month
- DateInterval.Quarter
- DateInterval.Year